# How to install windows on Ubuntu Installed drive which i formatted using GParted Live CD

Tags: grub2

By mistake i formatted the drive in which Ubuntu 14 was installed by using GParted Live CD.
Now i want to install Windows to it, but nothing is booting up. I tried DVD and USB. All my pc showing up is GNU Grub. I don't know what to do??
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can install Using GParted from UNetbootin-PartedMagic
Another approach to resizing partitions, which does not require a CD, is to load PartedMagic from Windows via the UNetbootin PartedMagic Loader:

- Download and install the Windows (.exe) file, then reboot.
- Select the UNetbootin-partedmagic entry after rebooting, and wait as
  PartedMagic boots up.
- Start the partition manager by clicking the GParted icon on the the
  panel.
- Select your disk (probably /dev/sda) via the drop-down menu on the
  top-right corner of the interface.
- Right-click the NTFS partition to be resized (probably /dev/sda1),
  and select the "resize" option.
- Drag the slider to specify the new size the NTFS partition should be
  resized to, then press OK.
- Press the "Apply" button to resize the disk, then reboot once done.

  Upon the next Windows boot, click OK when prompted to remove UNetbootin-partedmagic to remove its boot menu entry.

Source  : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about Ubuntu, but however!

First insert windows disk and boot it, then go to fix section and fix the windows startup